# How can I write a function that will create and store variables?

Tags: matlab, function, memoization

I would like to have a function `function y(x)` that, when I call `y(5.12)` will create a variable y(5.12) (or somehow remember what y(5.12) is) that will be available for use after the function is done running. What is the easiest way to do something like that?

I would've made an array and just stored each value in its corresponding cell, but I will also have non-integer and negative values, so array wouldn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried a `containers.Map`, maybe in a `persistent` variable?

Comment: I've actually been trying to figure out how `persistent` works on and off for the past couple of days with some other part of the code and have ended up using a different method (global) every time ... that function is still very mysterious to me ... could you be more specific please? I'm not entire sure how it works, let along how to apply it here. I will look into containers.Map now though, I've never used it

Comment: Use `persistent` instead of `global`; your code will work better in the long run. The [doco for persistent](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) covers it. `persistent` means the variable keeps its value across multiple invocations of the function. Clearing the function (which happens implicitly when you change and save the function) will reset its persistent variables' values; maybe that's where the confusion is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew Janke is spot on.  Use a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html).  `containers.Map` is what is known as an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).  It's also known as a symbol table, map, or dictionary.  The backbone behind an associative array is that you access the array by a **key** and you get an associated value accompanied with this key.

The best example would be an English dictionary where the key is the word you want to look up, and the value is the definition of that particular word.  For example (without any embellishment), supposing that our dictionary was `f`, and I used the key `rayryeng`, a possible value could be:

```
f('rayryeng') --> he is awesome
```

Now in MATLAB, the list of possible key types are: `'char', 'double', 'single', 'int32', 'uint32', 'int64', or 'uint64'`.  The list of possible values are `'char', 'logical', 'double', 'single', 'int8', 'uint8', 'int16', 'uint16', 'int32', 'uint32', 'int64', or 'uint64'`.  Given your application, it sounds like you want the key to be a `double` and the value to be a `char`.

As such, initialize your `containers.Map` to recognize this key/value combination:

```
f = containers.Map('KeyType','double','ValueType','char')
```

We get this:

```
f = 

  Map with properties:

        Count: 0
      KeyType: double
    ValueType: char
```

There are currently no key/value pairs in this dictionary, and the expected key is a `double` and the output value is a `char`.  We can start adding things at will:

```
>> f(5.12) = 'hello';
>> f(-1.56) = 'Solarmew';
>> f(pi) = 'YES!';
```

I've added in 3 keys of 5.12, -1.56 and `pi` with different strings.  Now, if you want to retrieve a value given a key, just give the right key:

```
>> x = f(-1.56)

x =

Solarmew
```

If you try and give a key that doesn't exist, MATLAB will give you an error:

```
>> y = f(0)

Error using containers.Map/subsref
The specified key is not present in this container.
```

If you want to check to see if a key exists in the dictionary, use the `isKey` method:

```
>> isKey(f, 0)

ans = 

  0
```

Some more methods for you.  You can retrieve all keys in the dictionary currently with the `keys` method:

```
>> k = keys(f)

k = 

    [-1.5600]    [3.1416]    [5.1200]
```

`k` is a cell array where each element is a key in this dictionary.  Similarly, if you want the values, use the `values` method:

```
>> v = values(f);

v = 

    'Solarmew'    'YES!'    'hello'
```

It should be noted that both `keys` and `values` doesn't guarantee any order.  This means that the order in which you added keys and values doesn't necessarily mean that you will get this same order when you call `keys` or `values`.  Lastly, if you want to **remove** a key/value pair from the dictionary, use the `remove` method:

```
>> remove(f, -1.56);
>> k = keys(f)

k = 

    [3.1416]    [5.1200]

>> v = values(f)

v = 

    'YES!'    'hello'
```

As you can see, the key of `-1.56` associated with `Solarmew` is now removed from the dictionary.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: cool stuff! :] still doesn't seem to be compatible with a function (where the actual assignments will be coming from)



`w = containers.Map('KeyType','double','ValueType','char');`

  `function wOut = w(z)
        wOut = w0*sqrt(1+(z/zr)^2);
        w(z) = wOut;
    end`

Comment: That's because you're not defining the function properly.  Make the `containers.Map` like you did, then use this as input into the function.  You're trying to make the function name and the `containers.Map` the same name.  Do this:  `function w = f(w, z, w0, zr) w(z) = w0*sqrt(1+(z/zr)^2); end`, then all you have to do is `w = f(w, z, w0, zr);` in the workspace.  `w` should now be updated with whatever you put in it.

Comment: still not working :( ... I typed into the workspace "w = containers.Map('KeyType','double','ValueType','char');", then edited my function called "test" to be "function w = test(z) %  w(z) = sqrt(z);    end" and typed "test(0.1) into workspace and it returned "Attempted to access (0.1); index must be a positive integer or logical."

Comment: w has to be an input into the function too. Please read my comment to you again. Good luck!

Comment: how can w be an input if w is a function itself? X.x ... all I was trying to do was to have the values of w(z) be remembered without the same one being calculated over and over again. If w(3) is called once, I want there to instantly exist a variable with the same name "w(3)" that other functions have access to... I don't know if that's possible in MatLab. I know that if you call w(3) once in Mathematica and then call it again, it's not going to plug 3 into w(z) and crack through the calculation, it will recognize that w(3) has been called before and just pull that value from memory.

Comment: Because you're trying to plot characters. Doesn't make sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78482/discussion-between-solarmew-and-rayryeng).

Answer (score 1):

I will present my solution using a simple array and a `persistent` variable.

Consider that you have a function that computes the square of a number and you want to do some memoization.

In my code, `my_hist` is a 2 dimensional vector. The first dimension corresponds to the input and the second to the square of the input (i.e., the output).

```
function y = memo_sqr(x)

persistent my_hist;

if(isempty(my_hist))
 my_hist = [0 0];
end

%Find if it is already present

idx = find(my_hist(:,1)==x);

if idx
 disp('Found Entry in Table')
 y = my_hist(idx,2)
 return
end

y = x^2;

my_hist = [my_hist; x y];

pause(2); %Artifical Lag 

end
```

I introduce some artifical lag of 2 seconds to simulate the case where the calculation is time-consuming.

Now, if I run the code for the first time asking for `memo_sqr(x)`, it takes some odd 2 seconds to compute (which includes the artifical lag). However, if I ask for it again, the persistent look-up table gives me the answer right away.

```
>> tic; memo_sqr(2); toc;
Elapsed time is 2.056881 seconds.
>> tic; memo_sqr(2); toc;
Found Entry in Table

y =

     4

Elapsed time is 0.000545 seconds.
```

---

This is obviously a very simplistic example but it highlights how `persistent` variables can be used. Individual steps of my snippet can be optimized to fit your needs.

Comment: @Solarmew, this is just an illustration. If you use a cell-array instead of an array, you can fit any datastructure in there.

Comment: I'll just have to take your word for it +.+ ... I have no idea how that would work.